# MySQL "Unable to connect to host [host] because access was denied."

Tags: mysql, wildcard, remote-access, access-denied

I'm having an issue connecting remotely to my MySQL server.  I know my user is setup with the '%' wildcard from any host, so I should have access to the server.  I can log in locally on  the MySQL server with my credentials, just not remotely.

My settings in my.cnf look like this:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#
bind-address            = 128.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And I'm connecting with the following params (using Coda2 GUI -- but the problem doesn't seem related to Coda2):

```
Server: 128.xxx.xxx.xxx
Port: 3306
Username: sadmicrowave
Password: my_mysql_password
```

The full error message posted is:

```
 Unable to connect to host uslonsweb003 because access was denied.
 Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

 MySQL said: Access denied for user 'sadmicrowave'@'128.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

I can telnet to my server using IP address and 3306 so I know the server is listening on that port...

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Did you issued [the flush privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html) after granting access to the wildcard user?

What happens if you add an entry with user = sadmicrowave and host = [your actual ip] (don't forget to issue the flush privileges command after adding the user) ?

Comment: I've rebooted since the user name add, which ( from what I've read) will do the same thing as the flush command.

Comment: I'd certainly try to add the user with your local ip as host and see what it does.